# Is there a zipWith analogue for tuples?

Tags: haskell, tuples, applicative

*Preliminary note: this is a respin of [a deleted question by SeanD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50020370/2751851).*

Just like there is `zipWith` for lists...

```
GHCi> zipWith (+) [1,2] [3,4]
[4,6]
```

... it feels like there should be something analogous for tuples, in the spirit of...

```
tupleZipWith (+) (1,2) (3,4)
```

... but there doesn't seem to be anything obviously like that in *base*. Which options do I have?

Comment: I think it's a shame the original Q got deleted. I really hope that it's because the questioneer figured out his problem on his own, and not that he felt like we were piling on to him. (I personally felt everyone was being polite and trying to help, but things can get lost in translation on the internet, and words have a tendency to hurt people's feelings even unintentionally. If you're reading this, SeanD, I apologise if I came over as rude or condescending.)

Comment: Let me add that I entirely agree with @BenjaminHodgson on that.

Comment: There is also [fixed-vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector) package

Comment: Now the previous question has been undeleted. It's a bit weird to undelete a question when the asker was the deleter -- in some cases, it feels bad to override their own choice. However, SO lets us do it, and in this case I think (hope?) it was justified.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I honestly believe the intent was good, but I thought the discussion was just unproductive and I decided that that was my fault for not asking the question properly.

Answer (score 11):

One option is using the [*tuples-homogenous-h98*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuples-homogenous-h98-0.1.1.0) package, which provides newtype wrappers for homogeneous tuples that have appropriate `Applicative` instances:

```
GHCi> import Data.Tuple.Homogenous
GHCi> import Control.Applicative
GHCi> liftA2 (+) (Tuple2 (1,2)) (Tuple2 (3,4))
Tuple2 {untuple2 = (4,6)}
GHCi> (>) <$> Tuple3 (7,4,7) <*> Tuple3 (6,6,6)
Tuple3 {untuple3 = (True,False,True)}
```

If you have a favourite homogenous tuple/fixed-size vector/fixed-size list library other than *tuples-homogenous-h98*, odds are that it will also have suitable `ZipList`-like `Applicative` instances.

---

For a slightly different take on the matter when it comes to pairs, you might want to consider [`Data.Biapplicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5.2/docs/Data-Biapplicative.html) from *bifunctors*:

```
GHCi> import Data.Biapplicative
GHCi> bimap (+) (+) (1,2) <<*>> (3,4)
(4,6)
```

One nice thing about this approach is that it can handle heterogeneous pairs:

```
GHCi> bimap (+) (+) (1,2.5) <<*>> (3,4)
(4,6.5)
GHCi> bimap (+) (++) (1,"foo") <<*>> (3,"bar")
(4,"foobar")
```

Comment: There's also `uncurry (***) :: (a -> c, b -> d) -> (a, b) -> (c, d)` but, like `Biapplicative`, that only works on pairs, so doesn't address the original now-deleted question.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson In a similar spirit, it would be nice if `dup = id &&& id` were defined in `Control.Arrow`, or somewhere similarly standard-ish. That way, I'd be able to suggest `dup (+) <<*>> (1,2) <<*>> (3,4)` without a second thought.

Answer (score 6):

Using GHC Generics, we can define operations that only depend on the structure of a type (the number of constructor and their arities).

We want a function `zipWithP` that takes a function `f` and zips two tuples applying `f` between matching fields. Perhaps something with a signature matching this:

```
zipWithP
  :: forall c s. _
  => (forall s. c s => s -> s -> s) -> a -> a -> a
```

Here `f :: forall s. c s => s -> s -> s` is polymorphic, allowing the tuple to be heterogeneous, as long as the fields are all instances of `c`. That requirement will be captured by the `_` constraint, which is up to the implementation, as long as it works.

There are libraries that capture common constructions, notably [*one-liner*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/one-liner-1.0) and [*generics-sop*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.3.2.0).

In increasing order of automation...

---

The classical solution is to use the [`GHC.Generics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) module. A `Generic` instance represents an isomorphism between a user-defined type `a` and an "generic representation" `Rep a` associated with it.

This generic representation is constructed from a fixed set of types defined in [`GHC.Generics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html). (The documentation of the module has more details about that representation.)

The standard steps are:

1. define functions on that fixed set of types (possibly a subset of it);
2. adapt them to user-defined types by using the isomorphism given by a `Generic` instance.

Step 1 is typically a type class. Here `GZipWith` is the class of generic representations that can be zipped. The type constructors handled here are, in decreasing order of importance:

- `K1` represents fields (just apply `f`);
- `(:*:)` represents type products (zip the operands separately);
- the `M1` newtype carries information at the type-level, that we aren't using here so we just wrap/unwrap with it;
- `U1` represents nullary constructors, mostly for completeness.

Step 2 defines `zipWithP` by composing `gZipWith` with `from`/`to` where appropriate.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.Generics

class GZipWith c f where
  gZipWith :: (forall s. c s => s -> s -> s) -> f p -> f p -> f p

instance c a => GZipWith c (K1 _i a) where
  gZipWith f (K1 a) (K1 b) = K1 (f a b)

instance (GZipWith c f, GZipWith c g) => GZipWith c (f :*: g) where
  gZipWith f (a1 :*: a2) (b1 :*: b2) = gZipWith @c f a1 b1 :*: gZipWith @c f a2 b2

instance GZipWith c f => GZipWith c (M1 _i _c f) where
  gZipWith f (M1 a) (M1 b) = M1 (gZipWith @c f a b)

instance GZipWith c U1 where
  gZipWith _ _ _ = U1

zipWithP
  :: forall c a. (Generic a, GZipWith c (Rep a))
  => (forall s. c s => s -> s -> s) -> a -> a -> a
zipWithP f a b = to (gZipWith @c f (from a) (from b))

main = do
  print (zipWithP @Num (+) (1,2) (3,4) :: (Int, Integer))
```

---

[*generics-sop*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.3.2.0) provides high-level combinators to program generically with operations that feel like `fmap`/`traverse`/`zip`...

In this case, the relevant combinator is `hcliftA2`, which zips generic heterogeneous tuples of fields with a binary function. More explanations after the code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))
import Generics.SOP

zipWithP
  :: forall c a k
  .  (Generic a, Code a ~ '[k], All c k)
  => (forall s. c s => s -> s -> s) -> a -> a -> a
zipWithP f x y =
  case (from x, from y) of
    (SOP (Z u), SOP (Z v)) ->
      to (SOP (Z (hcliftA2 (Proxy :: Proxy c) (liftA2 f) u v)))

main = do
  print (zipWithP @Num (+) (1,2) (3,4) :: (Int, Integer))
```

Starting from the top of `zipWithP`.

Constraints:

- `Code a ~ '[k]`: `a` must be a single-constructor type (`Code a :: [[*]]` is the list of constructors of `a`, each given as the list of its fields).
- `All c k`: all fields of the constructor `k` satisfy the constraint `c`.

Body:

- `from` maps from regular type `a` to a generic Sum Of Products (`SOP I (Code a)`).
- We assumed that the type `a` has a single constructor. We apply that knowledge by pattern-matching to get rid of the "sum" layer. We get `u` and `v`, whose types are *products* (`NP I k`).
- We apply `hcliftA2` to zip the two tuples `u` and `v`.
- Fields are wrapped in a type constructor `I`/`Identity` ([functor-functor](https://www.benjamin.pizza/posts/2017-12-15-functor-functors.html) or [HKD](http://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/) style), hence there is also a `liftA2` layer on top of `f`.
- We get a new tuple, and go backwards from the first two steps, by applying constructors and `to` (the inverse of `from`).

See the generics-sop documentation for more details.

---

`zipWithP` belongs to a class of operations that are commonly described by "do this for each field". [*one-liner*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/one-liner) exports operations, some of whose names may look familiar (`map...`, `traverse...`), that are essentially specializations of a single "generalized traversal" associated with any generic type.

In particular, `zipWithP` is called `binaryOp`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Generics.OneLiner

main = print (binaryOp @Num (+) (1,2) (3,4) :: (Int, Integer))
```

Comment: Nice; it is good to have a comprehensive generics-powered answer here.