# Is there a Haskell lens function for "zipping" same-length tuples?

Tags: haskell, tuples, haskell-lens

I would like to be able to combine two tuples of the same length using a function, similar to the `zipWith` function from `base`.
For example, for the case of length 3 tuples:

```hs
zipTupleWith f (a0,a1,a2) (b0,b1,b2) = (f a0 b0, f a1 b1, f a2 b2)
```

Though I would like a single function that works for any length.

I have made a function `zipTupleWith` using the `lens` package:

```hs
zipTupleWith :: (Each s1 t1 a a, Each s2 s2 b b) => (a -> b -> a) -> s1 -> s2 -> t1
zipTupleWith f a b = a & partsOf each %~ flip (zipWith f) (b ^.. each)
```

This can `zipWith` two tuples so long as the function is of type `a -> b -> a`. This restriction is because of the `partsOf` function being used on the argument `a`.

There are 3 reasons that I'm not happy with my solution:

1. I would like to be able to use a function of type `a -> b -> c`, allowing things like `zipTuple = zipTupleWith (,)`.
2. The above implementation will not catch errors caused by tuples of different lengths being passed in (`zipTupleWith (+) (1,2,3) (100,100) = (101, 102, 3)` - I would like this to be a compilation error).
3. It creates an intermediary list (`b ^.. each`).

So, is there a way of doing this using optics?
I saw that the `tuple-th` package can do this, but I would prefer to avoid adding another dependency just for this, and Template Haskell seems excessive for what I'm doing.

Comment: Can you migrate from using a tuple to using a [sized `Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-sized-1.4.3.1/docs/Data-Vector-Sized.html), which supports zips of arbitrary arity via its `Applicative` instance (and fixed small arity via the usual `zipWith`, `zipWith3`, etc. names)?

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for the suggestion, but I would prefer to stick with tuples if possible.

Comment: Can you say a bit about why?

Comment: (1) I would prefer not to have to rewrite existing code that uses tuples, (2) performance/memory concerns: to quote the readme of `vector-sized` "this approach requires us to carry a runtime representation of length, which is a significant memory overhead for small vectors.". My tuples are small.

Comment: Why do you want a lens based solution? You're not using lenses in the interface, so why do you care how it's implemented? I suspect that anything that builds this functionality out of an ability to generically traverse tuples (like `Each`) is going to struggle to avoid your problems 2 and 3. But you can really easily make a type class solution, and if your tuples are small then you don't need many instances so the boilerplate isn't too bad.

Comment: Hm. I wonder if that documentation is outdated. You can see [in the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-sized-1.4.3.1/docs/src/Data.Vector.Generic.Sized.Internal.html#Vector) that `Vector`s do not carry a runtime representation of their length (or at least not any extra such representation compared to the efficient underlying `vector` package's `Vector`s).

Comment: @Ben Lenses are not strictly required, I just meant that I would prefer to avoid adding another dependency just to do this.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think the runtime representation of length that they are referring to _is_ the one that the `vector` package's `Vector` contains.

Comment: Related (but not optics-based): [*Is there a zipWith analogue for tuples?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50032674)

Comment: Seconded on using a sized vector.  Tuples are not the right data structure when you need to treat different positions uniformly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you asked for a lens-based approach, but if you only have small tuples, you can implement what you want with a type class without too much trouble.  Consider for instance:

```hs
class ZipTuple as a where
  type TupOf as x :: *
  zipTuple :: (a -> b -> c) -> as -> TupOf as b -> TupOf as c

instance ZipTuple (a,a) a where
  type TupOf (a,a) b = (b,b)
  zipTuple f (a1,a2) (b1,b2) = (f a1 b1, f a2 b2)

instance ZipTuple (a,a,a) a where
  type TupOf (a,a,a) b = (b,b,b)
  zipTuple f (a1,a2,a3) (b1,b2,b3) = (f a1 b1, f a2 b2, f a3 b3)
```

There may be a more elegant way to write this, but the pattern is straightforward.  It should be easy to add instances for whatever length tuples you want.

---

If you want arbitrarily long tuples but don't want template haskell, there's also the Generics route.  Here's a solution that zips based on the shape of the generic representation:

```hs
import GHC.Generics

class TupleZipG fa fb a b c | fa -> a, fb -> b where
  type Out fa fb a b c :: (* -> *)
  tupleZipG :: (a -> b -> c) -> fa x -> fb x -> Out fa fb a b c x

instance (TupleZipG l1 l2 a b c, TupleZipG r1 r2 a b c) => TupleZipG (l1 :*: r1) (l2 :*: r2) a b c where
  type Out (l1 :*: r1) (l2 :*: r2) a b c = Out l1 l2 a b c :*: Out r1 r2 a b c
  tupleZipG f (l1 :*: r1) (l2 :*: r2) = tupleZipG f l1 l2 :*: tupleZipG f r1 r2

instance TupleZipG (S1 m (Rec0 a)) (S1 m' (Rec0 b)) a b c where
  type Out (S1 m (Rec0 a)) (S1 m' (Rec0 b)) a b c = S1 m (Rec0 c)
  tupleZipG f (M1 (K1 a)) (M1 (K1 b)) = M1 $ K1 $ f a b

instance TupleZipG fa fb a b c => TupleZipG (D1 m fa) (D1 m' fb) a b c where
  type Out (D1 m fa) (D1 m' fb) a b c = D1 m (Out fa fb a b c)
  tupleZipG f (M1 a) (M1 b) = M1 $ tupleZipG f a b

instance TupleZipG fa fb a b c => TupleZipG (C1 m fa) (C1 m' fb) a b c where
  type Out (C1 m fa) (C1 m' fb) a b c = C1 m (Out fa fb a b c)
  tupleZipG f (M1 a) (M1 b) = M1 $ tupleZipG f a b

tupleZip
  :: (TupleZipG (Rep as) (Rep bs) a b c, Generic cs, Generic as,
      Generic bs, Out (Rep as) (Rep bs) a b c ~ Rep cs) =>
     (a -> b -> c) -> as -> bs -> cs
tupleZip f t1 t2 = to $ tupleZipG f (from t1) (from t2)
```

Warning: Type inference isn't great with this Generic approach.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could do something like this:

```
zipTupleWith :: (Each s s a a, Each t v b c, Each t s b a)
  => (a -> b -> c) -> s -> t -> v
zipTupleWith f s t = t & unsafePartsOf each %~ zipWith f (s ^.. each)
```

giving:

```
> zipTupleWith replicate (1,2,3) ('a','b','c')
("a","bb","ccc")
> zipTupleWith (+) (1,2) (3,4,5)
-- type error
```

The trick here is the "extra" contraint `Each t s b a`.  The other two contraints are implied by the two uses of `each` -- basically, `Each s s a a` is implied by the expression `s ^.. each` that extracts all the `a`s from s, while `Each t v b c` is implied by `t & unsafePartsOf each %~ ...` for some `... :: [b] -> [c]`.  But adding the otherwise unnecessary constraint `Each t s b a` enforces equal tuple length at the type level by asserting that **IF** every `b` in `t` was replaced with an `a`, the result would be an `s`.

Note that `lens` isn't doing anything magical here.  There's an `Each` instance for a bunch of different sized tuples, and there's just enough information in the type class to trick it into defining `zipTupleWith` in a really ugly, roundabout manner.

It would be much more straightforward to just define the type class you need directly, as per @DDub's answer.